# MAPE changes when unnormalizing the data

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I'm doing some regression analysis and in the preprocessing of the data first I'm taking log1p and then I'm normalizing the data. When done like that I'm getting MAPE around 0.94 % bu when I'm unnormalizing the predicted output and then calculate the MAPE against the original data I'm getting MAPE around 8.7 %. Why is that happening? Am I loosing information in significant digits of normalized data ?

Comment: This should not be really surprising. The logarithm is not a linear transformation so the MAPE between the original scale and the logarithmic one can vary wildly.

Comment: So, what's the solution ?

Comment: Not transforming your data and/or accepting that when using a non-linear transformation linear measurement of dispersion will vary wildly. In a sense, there is no problem to be solved, just the effects of a transformation to be appreciated. :)

Comment: I have seen many codes using lop1p for transforming the data, why would anyone want to do that then ?

Comment: In many cases the sole purpose of log transformation is to allow use of linear regression rather than non-linear regression.

Comment: I used a Maxmin transformation, I see the MAPE value change in this case as well, is this normal? I have been thinking about it for a few days now :D @usεr11852